# Error incurred upon truncating a diagonal matrix to only the k largest eigenvalues.

Tags: matrices, diagonalization, block-matrices, spectral-norm

Say I have a diagonal matrix (A) of dim n x n.  What is the error incurred if I approximate it with only its k-largest eigenvalues? I am using the 1-norm. I am trying to quantify the error in the following manner:
Err=||A||-||A1||, where ||A|| is the original diagonal matrix and ||A1|| is the truncated diagonal matrix.

Comment: How do you measure the error? Which matrix norm are you using?

Comment: Thanks, I have clarified the points by editing the question.